# ¿Como saber si mi JTextFiel contiene texto y este está seleccionado?

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo mi campo declarado y con `campo.setSelectionStart(0)` y `campo.setSelectionEnd(12)` logro que el texto se seleccione pero no puedo comprobar si este texto está seleccionado. Busco algo como `campo.isTextSelected()` o algo que vaya por esa línea.

Intente esto:

```
if (campo.getSelectionEnd()==campo.getText().length()) {
    reutrn true;
}
```

Pero `getSelectionEnd()` siempre sigue creciendo y me da true indistintamente. La idea es limitar el número de caracteres que escribo pero si está seleccionado no, de manera que la selección se sobre escriba.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo se me ocurre que tu método `boolean` simplemente contenga:

`return campo.getSelectedText() != null;`

***... y entonces ocurre lo uno o lo otro:***

1. Obtenemos `true` si hay texto con highlight, básicamente porque `getSelectedText()` contendría y retornaría un dato `String` que automaticamente lo haría distinto de `null`.
2. Obtenemos `false` cuando no tengamos texto seleccionado, ya que `getSelectedText()` sera **igual** a `null`.

Espero ayude.